# Why is my API getting undefined values from fetch calls?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

In my login system for my react project, I have created a loginForm component that sends a username and password my backend. I know that the backend is properly called on submit due to my console logs in the api returning "undefined" for the username and password values entered. Whatever I have done, I have not been able to get this to properly be sent to my api for authentication. Does anyone have any idea why this may be the case? The code is listed below:

server.js :

```
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const cors = require('cors');
const session = require('express-session');
const MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session');



// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors())
const port = 5000;

app.listen(port, () => `Server running on port ${port}`);

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  let username = req.body.username;
  let password = req.body.password;

  console.log(username)
  console.log(password)
})
```

InputField.js (my input component. It consists of a SubmitButton component, and inputField component)

```
import InputField from '../components/InputField';
import SubmitButton from '../components/SubmitButton';
import UserStore from '../Stores/UserStore';


class LoginForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
            this.state = {
                username:  '',
                password:  '',
                buttonDisabled: false

            }
        }

            SetInputValue(property, val) {
                val = val.trim();
                if (val.length > 12) {
                    return;
                }
                this.setState({
                    [property]: val
                })
        }
        
    resetForm() {
        this.setState({
            username: '',
            password: '',
            buttonDisabled: false
        })
    }

    async doLogin() {
        
        if (!this.state.username) {
            return;
        }
        if (!this.state.password) {
            return;
        }

        this.setState({
            buttonDisabled: true
        })

        try {
            console.log(this.state.username)
            console.log(this.state.password)
            const payLoad = {username: this.state.username, password: this.state.password};
            let res = await fetch('/login', { 
                method: "POST",
                mode: "cors",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application.json",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
                }, 
                body: JSON.stringify(this.state ) 
            });
            let result = await res.json();
            if (result && result.success) {
                UserStore.isLoggedIn = true; 
                UserStore.username = result.username;
            }
            else if (result && result.success === false) {
                this.resetForm();
                alert(result.msg); 
            }
        }

        catch(e) {
            console.log(e)
            this.resetForm();
        }


    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div> 
                  
            Log in
            <InputField 
                type='text'
                placeholder='Username'
                value={this.state.username ? this.state.username : ''}
                onChange={ (val) => this.SetInputValue('username', val) }
            />
         
            <InputField 
                type='password'
                placeholder='Password'
                value={this.state.password ? this.state.password : ''}
                onChange={ (val) => this.SetInputValue('password', val) }
            />

            <SubmitButton 
                text='Login'
                disabled={this.state.buttonDisabled}
                onClick={ () => this.doLogin() }
            />
            

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default LoginForm;
```

I can post the other components if necessary--don't want to overflow this post.  From what I have troubleshooted, my frontend is fine (the payload is correct when examined in my browser's web tools). Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **RESPONSE** header. Remove it from your request

Comment: You have a typo. `"Content-Type": "application.json"` should be `"Content-Type": "application/json"`

Comment: I think you want if (result && res.success)  rather than if (result && result.success). The success property is going to be on the response object, not response body serialized to json.

Comment: Your `/login` request handler does not send any response so, there's nothing for the `fetch()` to get.  You need a `res.send()` or `res.json()` in that request handler.